# View html files from sub folders

Tags: html

I have a website. I have files under a html folder.

```
http://www.mysite.com/html/1.html
http://www.mysite.com/html/2.html
http://www.mysite.com/html/3.html
```

I want to make it like, if someone hits

```
http://www.mysite.com/1.html
http://www.mysite.com/2.html
http://www.mysite.com/3.html
```

they have to view the files from the html folder. However, the url in the address bar should stay as the user typed. Also, we have some images used by these html files under `http://www.mysite.com/html/images` folder.

I usually edit the html using dreamweaver and upload it via ftp.

I know many people are doing this. but I am not sure how to do it?

My site is hosted in a linux host I believe. It is shared one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to move the files, and depending on the server setup.  You might want to look into .htaccess mod_rewrite rules which are how many people do this.

http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

Answer (score 0):

If you want this you can try to put your 1.html, 2.html and 3.html files on the root of your server. Hope this is a suitable solution for you.

Comment: I dont' want to put all the files in root directory, as there are 500+ files.